# order of declaration in layout

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc-5, visual-studio-2013

newbie in web dev, try to do stuff that involved jquery as well, for example dropkick drop down extension.

When I include jquery-1.10.2.min.js in the bundleConfig it doesn't work:

```
public static void RegisterBundles(BundleCollection bundles)
    {
        bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/jquery").Include(
                    "~/Scripts/jquery-{version}.min.js",
                    "~/Scripts/jquery-ui.js",
                    "~/Scripts/jquery.dropkick.js"
                    ));...
```

but only when I explicit refer to that in _layout.cshtml under  (before the dropkick script I added) it is working.

```
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery-1.10.2.min.js" type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8"></script>   
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">

    $( document ).ready(function () {
        $('.default').dropkick();....
```

Got below errors, searched around, and seems like my order is ok - first jquery, then jquery ui, so I'm not sure what are my next steps here

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined ParentInvite:35
Uncaught ReferenceError: jQuery is not defined jquery-ui.js:314
Uncaught ReferenceError: jQuery is not defined jquery.dropkick.js:555
Invalid App Id: Must be a number or numeric string representing the application id.
```

Answer (score 1):

By default, the bundler won't let you reference `.min` files in your bundle list. Change the jQuery reference to `"~/scripts/jquery-{version}.js"` and it will work.

It's also worth noting that as long as you have both the development and the `.min` versions in your project, the bundler is smart enough to use the `.min` version when you switch your compilation mode to `Release`.